# How can we predetermine number of Spark jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

From what I experiences a Spark driver can run multiple jobs for a given application that get broken down into tasks in stages per executor.

What I cant seem to understand is when and why will one sparkcontext run more than 1 job?

Answer (score 0):

There is 1..* relationship between actions and jobs. Each action requires at least one job, but may transparently trigger additional action (for example to compute statistics).

Comment: is it to say then that one action requires one job?